# std::cin with more complex objects

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io, c++14, iostream

I have a text file which first describes some lines and then describes some colorful lines:

```
1 2    3  4
5 6    7  8 
9 10   11 12

red    1 0 0    1 2    3 4
green  0 1 0    5 6    7 8
blue   0 0 1    9 10   11 12
```

The number of lines in each section is *unknown* at time of execution
I overloaded the `std::cin >>` operator for these structs:

```
struct Point { int x, y; }
struct Line { Point a, b; }
struct Color { float r, g, b; std::string name; };
struct ColorfulLine { Line line; Color color; };
```

(Full example here: http://ideone.com/bMOaL1 [already works - edited according to the accepted answer])
Now I need to iterate over the file using `Lines` and `ColorfulLines`:

```
Line line;                                                     
while(cin >> line) { cout << "We've got a line!\n"; }              

ColorfulLine color_line;                                         
while(cin >> color_line) { cout << "We've got a colorful line!\n"; } 

// actually I'm putting them into std::lists but I skipped this part for simplicity
```

And here is the problem - the colorful lines are never fetched, i.e. the second loop is not executed.

I have an assumption *why* it happens but don't know how to fix it:
When `std::cin` tries to fetch the 4th Line, it fails because instead of a number there's the string "red".
Next, in the second while loop, std::cin tries to read a string (Color.name) but it sees a number, and then fails too.

I tried to put some random word before the ColorfulLines section hoping that when the first loop fails, the second will start reading from the "red" string, but it didn't.

**How to fix this?**

Comment: Explanation of reasons for downvote will be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'd wager it's because you posted the relevant code offsite instead of directly in your question. (Please don't do this in the future.)

Comment: @ildjarn the relevant code is all in the question, I skipped only the `>>` operator overload which I find unnecesarry to be here. (and of course int main and co.). Am I wrong? I thought it'd be better if I leave here only the most important parts and not the whole junk out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the first loop breaks, `std::cin` is in a bad state. That's why the loop breaks in the first place. Performing reads on a bad stream fails immediately, thus the second loop is never entered.

To solve this, reset the error state after the first loop breaks with

```
std::cin.clear();
```